# What's the simplest way to do cross-browser rounded borders in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

I'm not after the 'best' way, that requires a lot of work doing large changes for different browsers, but the 'best easy' way... ideally the least horrible way that would work unchanged on IE7+, FF2+, Chrome. Tables are an option but probably a little *too* archaic. Is there a middle ground, which uses CSS without a lot of hassle?

And, if you want your borders to be more advanced than simple lines, are images+tables the best/only way, or is there a neat CSS+images solution?

Comment: Firefox 8 is out? Wow, their release cycle has sped up

Answer (score 1):

[Facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) uses tables, it's pretty much the easiest way to do it and support IE(6|7|8). Otherwise, I'd use [border-radius](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/) and deliver some non-rounded corners to IE(6|7|8), which is what Google did for the longest time.

Comment: Absolutely this is the best and easiest.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know if javascript is an option, but if it is, I would recommend [jQuery Corner](http://malsup.com/jquery/corner/).

It applies css corners to the browsers that support them and scripts corners for the browsers that don´t (IE...).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the CSS Play site, it has a lot of "[snazzy borders](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/snazzy2.html)" and "[krazy korners](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/krazy.html)"

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like to use the "[sliding door](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/)" technique.

The method you use depends on what elements you need to have round corners. Are they going to be fixed width or height? Thats the major question. If you have a fixed width, you can simply make a top image (bkg_top.jpg) and a bottom image (bkg_bottom.jpg) then put the one inside the other.

lets assume you want a 500px wide box with 10px rounded corners and a background color of #555555.

HTML:

```
<div id="content_box">
  <p>lorem ipsum...</p>
  <div id="content_box_bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content_box {
background: #555 url(bkg_top.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0 top;
padding-top:10px; /*the height of the top image*/
width:500px;
}

#content_box_bottom {
background: #555 url(bkg_bottom.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0 bottom;
height:10px; /* the height of the image */
}
```

The bottom div will strech to fill the content_box and create the bottom of the rounded box.

Thats just one example.
Here is another good web [rounded corners](http://www.schillmania.com/content/entries/2006/04/more-rounded-corners/)

Answer (score 0):

Agreed if the rounded-corner box is not fluid, and fixed in width then you should simply use 2 images as demonstrated above. 
You could even add the bottom rounded corner image to the last element appearing in the box depending on the circumstances (if it is a block element), this would have the advantage of not having additional markup which is always an advantage.